# which event handler would you use to catch a change to item in a bound combo box

Tags: keyboard-events

I have a bound combo box with a list of customer names.  I tried the key_down which fires when I change which name is in the combo box.  What I want is the event handler that will fire because that name is changing (like the spelling) not necessarily to a different name in the list.  I am thinking that I will need to write a block of code to test for a change in spelling.  Is there an event handler that will do the job?

I am working in Visual Studio using C# on a Windows form and SQL Server 2008

```
public Customer_Info_Form()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            button_Add_Customer.Visible = true;
            button_Add_Location.Visible = true;
            button_Save_Customer.Visible = false;
            button_Cancel_Customer_Add.Visible = false;
        }

private void Customer_Info_Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.customerTableAdapter.Fill(this.customer_Info_DataSet.Customer);
                this.customer_ShipTableAdapter.Fill(this.customer_Info_DataSet.Customer_Ship);
                this.termsTableAdapter.Fill(this.terms_DataSet.Terms);
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            }
        }

private void text_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button_Add_Customer.Visible = false;
            button_Add_Location.Visible = false;
            button_Save_Customer.Visible = true;
            button_Cancel_Customer_Add.Visible = true;
        }
```

the "text_Changed" event fires on form load.  it shouldn't fire until text is actually changed.  I choose "Cancel", the buttons are reset and as soon as I choose a different customer name the event fires again.  I haven't actually changed any of the text.  how do I keep the "text_Changed" event from firing until text is actually changed?

Comment: What environment? Web, Native App, Platform?  What language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event

It will be fired whenever the value of the ComboBox changes.

Answer (score 0):

when I tried the TextChanged event, it would fire as soon as the form would load and when I would select a different name in the bound combobox it would also fire rather then when the text actually changed.

in order to catch the change to the text of any selected item in the combobox I used the KeyDown event to catch a change to a name or any of the controls on the form.